# Select2 with Twitter Bootstrap 3 / Dropdown wrong width

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-select2

I want to use select2.js in combination with twitter bootstrap 3.
Everything works fine so far, except the fact, that the Drop-Down container has not the same width as the select container itself.

By resizing the window this phenomen appears and disappears.

Here is a picture that shows the issue [image: width issue]

And here is the jsfiddle where you can try the resizing. (Tested it with IE 11 and FF 26)
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AgwA4/)

And here also the code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/select2/3.4.5/select2.css">

<div class="container"> 
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <select style="width:100%" class="select2">
                <optgroup label="Test-group">    
                    <option>test1</option>
                    <option>test2</option>
                </optgroup>
            </select>
          </div>    
    <div class="col-xs-3">
            <select style="width:100%" class="select2">
                <optgroup label="Test-group">    
                    <option>test1</option>
                    <option>test2</option>
                </optgroup>
            </select>
          </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <select style="width:100%" class="select2">
                <optgroup label="Test-group">    
                    <option>test1</option>
                    <option>test2</option>
                </optgroup>
            </select>
          </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried to find a solution for hours now, but I can't find a solution for that issue.

Thank you and best regards

Comment: In case anyone has the same thought I did, adding `select2-bootstrap.css` [doesn't seem to help](http://jsfiddle.net/AgwA4/1/). (@user: Best to show in the question exactly what CSS you're loading, so people don't *have* to rely on the fiddle.)

Comment: Thank you for the hint and the try. I just added the css files used.

Answer (score 9):

Just embed your form with a `<form>` like here and tell your select to have a  `class="form-control"`. Follow the steps here http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal.

This will show your select2 combo correctly. Don't use style=**

Answer (score 5):

The jQuery plugin `select2` has some series CSS issues with `Bootstrap3` .. fortunately, there is a fix to these issues, [check out this github project](http://fk.github.io/select2-bootstrap-css/)

All you need to do is to add [this css file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fk/select2-bootstrap-css/master/select2-bootstrap.css) or simply append its contents to `select2.css`

Credit goes to [Jeff Mould](http://www.jeffmould.com/2014/02/25/using-select2-bootstrap-3/).

Answer (score 0):

For me, simply removing any additional styling (inline or class reference) from the select tag does the trick.

For example, the width for dropdown for the following was incorrect:

```
    <select class="select2 col-sm-10">
       <option></option>
       <option>test1</option>
       <option>test2</option>
    </select>
```

[image]

However, when I removed the `col-sm-10` class reference from select, the dropdown width was correct:

```
    <select class="select2">
       <option></option>
       <option>test1</option>
       <option>test2</option>
    </select>
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

Note that if I also add [this css file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fk/select2-bootstrap-css/master/select2-bootstrap.css), the dropdown is better than without doing anything; See below. but I prefer to simply remove all css styles (except select2) from select.
[image]